# jqtree cant load data with loadDataFromUrl function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jqtree

so here is my code

```
$('#parent').bind(
    'tree.click',
    function(event) {
        // The clicked node is 'event.node'
        var node = event.node;
        $('#parent').tree('loadDataFromUrl', 'g/admin/rules/getchildstwo/id/' + node.id, node,
            function() {
                alert('data is loaded');
            }
        );

        $('#parenthide').val(node.id);
    }
);
```

but callback function is not called and subtree is not loaded into node..i tried and loaded data seperatly with ajax and result is somthing like this:

```
{
    label: 'تست سمپل',
    id: 2540,
    section: '1',
    children: []
},


{
    label: 'hshhsh',
    id: 2541,
    section: '1',
    children: []
}
```

but still loadDataFromUrl not working and filling subtree..can anyone tell me whats wrong with my code or show me a working examlple of loading subtree wuth JQTree?

Comment: and by the way..i also tried loading data with following format `[
    
  
{label: 'تست سمپل', id: 2540,
section:  '1',
        children: []},

 
{label: 'hshhsh', id: 2541,
section:  '1',
        children: []},

 
]`

Comment: Your code have error or not worked?Perhaps `'tree.click'`  does not fired

Comment: no error,and tree.click s fired also...just loading data not working

Comment: json data loaded from server but jqx does not create tree?

Comment: exactly. jqx does not create tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
var data = [
    {
        label: 'تست سمپل', id: 2540,
        section:  '1',
        children: []
    },
    {
        label: 'hshhsh', id: 2541,
        section:  '1',
        children: []},
    }
];


$('#parent').tree({
   dataUrl: 'loadDataFromUrl',
  function() {
            alert('data is loaded');
        }
});
```

Comment: i want to load a sub tree by using ajax and 'loadDataFromUrl' method...your code is for instantiating jqtree for the first time

Comment: try with `dataUrl: 'loadDataFromUrl'`

Comment: by the way i'm sure 'tree.click' is firing

Comment: with `data :data` instead `dataUrl`  jqx tree worked for you?

Comment: so `loadDataFromUrl` not return valid json.put here `loadDataFromUrl` code